# How can I say "self-love" in Japanase?

Tags: meaning, word-requests

How can I say "self-love" in japanese, when you love yourself in a healthy way, not egoism?
Is 自愛 (Jiai) ok? And does the two pics mean same thing, with diff calligraphy?[image: jiai1]
[image: jiai2]

Answer (score 4):

The word in your pictures is 自愛, but this is probably not the word you want. 自愛 means "to take care of oneself", and it is a word used almost exclusively in the final part of a formal greeting letter.

If you want to say "self-love" in some ethical or philosophical contexts, 自己愛 is the normal term. 自己愛 is often associated with narcissism (especially in medial contexts), but you can avoid the misunderstanding when you use it approprieately. (Still, if you want to use this in isolation, say, as a tattoo, you may want to reconsider...)

Comment: Thank you, so I will reconsider. The ideia was using for a tattoo.